# How many runnable thread is suitable in jvm?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am digging into the stack dumped by jstack to find out the reason why CPU usage is quite high. According to the stack, there are more than 200 threads RUNNABLE and 400 threads WAITING. Should I reduce the thread pool until RUNNABLE threads reducing to 8, which is the number of cores.

Is there any good documents about how to adjust the thread pool size.

There are many blogs suggesting to set thread pool size according to the time cost by waiting time and cpu time, but there is no idea tool to testing them. I am not quite familiar tuning java application, but it is common sense that only 8 thread can be executed at the same time in a machine with 8 cores.

Comment: Very complex topic. It doesn't has a simple answer.

Comment: "However many your CPU supports, minus however many seem to be persistently in use already". Less than that, you're leaving the CPU underutilized, more than that and you'll slowing down the work because of threads execution scheduling. So it depends entirely on both the hardware you're running on, and the software that hardware's already running, which will be different for every computer.

Comment: OTOH, in order to deal with varying loads, the Fork-Join system in Java by default uses 4 x the number of CPU cores so that the system doesn't get starved for threads.  600 total threads is probably too much but some number less than 100 is probably acceptable.  I'd be more concerned about why you have 600 threads in the first place, it seems like something is generating too many threads and needs a different strategy.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just want to find a suitable pool size under the idea condition  .

Comment: @markspace 600 threads are created because the thread pool size is set to 600 now, and the QPS of this service is more than 1000. It seems like reducing the pool size to some number around 50 is a good idea.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, What do you mean by "However many your CPU supports?" Do you mean, however many your CPU can execute in parallel? That's great advice if the threads are working cooperatively to perform a massive calculation, but there are other reasons for using threads. In a web crawler, for example, it might make sense if, for every thread that actually was running on a CPU, there were ten other threads that were blocked, awaiting replies from different web sites.

Comment: @SolomonSlow tying back into the first comment.

Comment: @sion There are no ideal conditions, you're always going to have to juggle your own threads around whatever the rest of the system's doing, so figure out how many threads you absolutely need at minimum, and benchmark your project in terms of when adding more threads leads to diminishing returns. Ideally in a way that lets you do that analysis while your project's running so it can limit or expand the number of threads it's using. There are no simple solutions here, you picked one of the hardest problems to ask about.

Comment: Add details on which thread pool are you talking about, and what do those thread do - that may help you decide on more suitable balance.